# Hibernate search empty result with working query

Tags: java, hibernate, hibernate-search

Hibernate: 5.2.8.Final
Hibernate Search: 5.7.0.Final
Configuration:

```
spring.jpa.properties.hibernate.search.analyzer=org.apache.lucene.analysis.en.EnglishAnalyzer
logging.level.org.hibernate.search.fulltext_query=debug
```

My code:

```
FullTextEntityManager ftsEntityManager = Search.getFullTextEntityManager(entityManager);
        QueryBuilder queryBuilder = ftsEntityManager.getSearchFactory()
                .buildQueryBuilder().forEntity(Report.class).get();
        BooleanQuery.Builder builder = new BooleanQuery.Builder();
        BooleanQuery.Builder cmpBuilder = new BooleanQuery.Builder();
        companies.forEach(cmp -> cmpBuilder.add(
                NumericRangeQuery.newLongRange("merchant.company.company_id", cmp.getId(), cmp.getId(), true, true),
                BooleanClause.Occur.SHOULD));
        builder.add(cmpBuilder.build(), BooleanClause.Occur.MUST);
        builder.add(new TermQuery(new Term("status", status.name())), BooleanClause.Occur.MUST);
        org.apache.lucene.search.Query fromQuery = queryBuilder.range()
                .onField("createdAt")
                .above(from)
                .createQuery();
        org.apache.lucene.search.Query toQuery = queryBuilder.range()
                .onField("createdAt")
                .below(to)
                .createQuery();
        builder.add(fromQuery, BooleanClause.Occur.MUST);
        builder.add(toQuery, BooleanClause.Occur.MUST);           
        FullTextQuery fullTextQuery = ftsEntityManager.createFullTextQuery(builder.build(), Report.class);
        int results = fullTextQuery.getResultSize();
        EntityGraph graph = this.entityManager.getEntityGraph("Report.fetchMerchantAndAccount");
        List resultList = fullTextQuery
                .setFirstResult(pageable.getOffset())
                .setMaxResults(pageable.getPageSize())
                .setHint("javax.persistence.fetchgraph", graph)
                .getResultList();
```

Logged query:

```
2017-03-24 02:39:50.942 DEBUG 1984 --- [tp1560534902-96] org.hibernate.search.fulltext_query      : HSEARCH000274: Executing Lucene query '+(merchant.company.company_id:[2 TO 2]) +status:COMPLETE +createdAt:[0000020161102000000000000000 TO *] +createdAt:[* TO 0000020170324235959999999999]'
```

I've tested this query in the Luke and it works well:
[image]
Looks like the problem in this parameters `+(merchant.company.company_id:[2 TO 2]) +status:COMPLETE` but I can't figure out what is wrong.

Answer (score 0):

The problem was I should use QueryBuilder instead of Lucene classes.
So, changing this:

```
companies.forEach(cmp -> cmpBuilder.add(
                NumericRangeQuery.newLongRange("merchant.company.company_id", cmp.getId(), cmp.getId(), true, true),
                BooleanClause.Occur.SHOULD));
```

to this:

```
companies.forEach(cmp -> cmpBuilder.add(queryBuilder.range().onField("merchant.company.company_id")
                .from(cmp.getId()).to(cmp.getId()).createQuery(), BooleanClause.Occur.SHOULD));
```

and this:

```
builder.add(new TermQuery(new Term("status", status.name())), BooleanClause.Occur.MUST);
```

to this:

```
builder.add(queryBuilder.keyword().onField("status").matching(status).createQuery(), BooleanClause.Occur.MUST);
```

resolves a problem!